# Is this one infinite dimensional manifold?

Tags: general-topology, analysis, differential-geometry, manifolds

First of all, just to give context to the question: I've been reading some articles in Physics, and those articles imply without proof that one space is one infinite dimensional manifold. One of those articles is [this one](http://www.physics.utoronto.ca/~poppitz/poppitz/PHY1530_files/ShapereLowR.pdf) and the space I'm talking about is the "space of shapes" the article talks about.

The set in question is the set $Q$ of parametrizations of smooth surfaces in $\mathbb{R}^3$, that is, the injective smooth functions $S: U\subset \mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}^3$.

Now, I don't really want to accept on faith that this is one infinite dimensional manifold, but althought I've studied analysis on manifolds it was just on finite dimension, and I really don't even know where to start to tackle this. I don't even really know which natural topology could be given to this set.

I also heard that there are several types of infinite dimensional manifold, so I don't know of which type we are treating here.

So, is it possible to give this set a natural structure of infinite dimensional manifold? If yes, how can this be done?

Comment: The set of injective smooth functions from a fixed domain $U$ to $\mathbb{R}^3$ is different from what I would consider the set of parametrizations of a smooth surface. Can you please clarify? In any case, are you making any assumptions on $U$?

Comment: Based on the article, the domain is not really fixed, so one considers functions from different domains. Also there are not assumptions on $U$ being made. Which would you consider the set of parametrizations of smooth surfaces? I'll post one link to the article by the way, it might help to understand the question.

Comment: Your description make me suspect that you are talking about the [diffeomorphism group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffeomorphism#Diffeomorphism_group) which carries the structure of a Banach/Frechet manifold (infinite dimensional) depending on whether you are looking at smooth being $C^r$ or smooth being $C^\infty$. But perhaps you are referring to something different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, a clarification.

Let $S\subset\mathbb{R}^3$ be a two-dimensional compact submanifold. The "space of shapes" corresponding to $S$, according to the article you linked to, is the set $\mathscr{S}$ of $\mathbb{R}^3$-valued $C^1$ functions on $S$ which are injective and non-degenerate (in the meaning that the differential has full rank). In notation, $\mathscr{S}$ consists of $f:S\to \mathbb{R}^3$, injective, of class $C^1$, and $\mathrm{d}f$ has rank 2.

To see its manifold structure, first observe that the space $C^1(S:\mathbb{R}^3)$ of continuously differentiable $\mathbb{R}^3$-valued functions on $S$ is naturally a Banach space.

The fact that $\mathscr{S}$ is a Banach manifold follows from the fact that it is an open subset of $C^1(S:\mathbb{R}^3)$: observe simply that given $f\in \mathscr{S}$, for any $g\in C^1(S:\mathbb{R}^3)$ you can find some $\epsilon >0$ (here we used the compactness of $S$) such that for all $\delta < \epsilon$, the function $f \pm \delta g \in \mathscr{S}$.

---

In the case where $S$ is non-compact one has to be a bit more careful; the space $C^1(S:\mathbb{R}^3)$ is no longer Banach, but is Frechet. But considering compactly supported perturbations you again see, more-or-less analogously to above, that the corresponding $\mathscr{S}$ is an open subset and hence a Frechet manifold.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I understood your point, but I believe the space I'm talking about is a little different. The space $\mathscr{S}$ which you consider is the space of all possible deformations of a particular shape $S$. The space I'm talking about is the space of all possible shapes. So in truth, the space I'm talking about would be all possible parametrizations of surfaces. This space has any natural structure of a manifold?

Comment: My answered followed _exactly_ the description found on page 559 of the article you linked to. If you meant something else please give the precise definition.

Comment: sorry, after reading the article with a little more care I found out the definition you gave is really the precise one, and it makes much more sense. Thanks very much for your help!